# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected for setRequestProperty method : Java

Tags: java, httpurlconnection

I have created a class where I am creating an `HttpURLConnection` object and passing that object to another method if it passes the following condition:

*In this class I am passing `username`, `password` and `senderId` to connect to some URL using `proxy` when connection is not null.*

Below is complete code for the Java class:

```
public class SMSGenerator {
   public static HttpURLConnection sendSingleSMS(HttpURLConnection lconnection, String username,
       String password, String senderId,
       String mobileNo, String message) {
   try {
       String smsservicetype = "singlemsg"; // For single message.
       String query = "username=" + URLEncoder.encode(username)
               + "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(password)
               + "&smsservicetype=" + URLEncoder.encode(smsservicetype)
               + "&content=" + URLEncoder.encode(message) + "&mobileno="
               + URLEncoder.encode(mobileNo) + "&senderid="
               + URLEncoder.encode(senderId);

       lconnection.setRequestProperty("Content-length", String.valueOf(query.length()));
       lconnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
               "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
       lconnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
               "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.0; Windows 98; DigExt)");

       // open up the output stream of the connection
       DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(lconnection.getOutputStream());

       // write out the data
       int queryLength = query.length();
       output.writeBytes(query);
       // output.close();

       // get ready to read the response from the cgi script
       DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream(lconnection.getInputStream());

       // read in each character until end-of-stream is detected
       for (int c = input.read(); c != -1; c = input.read()) {
           System.out.print((char) c);
       }
       input.close();
   } catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.println("Something bad just happened.");
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   return lconnection;
}
public static boolean sendSMS(String mobilenumber, String msg) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
   boolean flag = false;
   Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("xxxxxxxxxx", xx));
   URL surl = new URL("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
   HttpURLConnection connection = null;
   connection = (HttpURLConnection) surl.openConnection(proxy);
   connection.setDoInput(true);
   connection.setDoOutput(true);
   connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
   HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(true);
   System.out.println("Response code " + connection.getResponseMessage());
   System.out.println("code : " + connection.getResponseCode() + " " + HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
   if ("OK".equals(connection.getResponseMessage())) {
       System.out.println("in");
       SMSGenerator.sendSingleSMS(connection, "username", "password", "SMS", mobilenumber, msg);
//             System.out.println("Sent successful SMS");
       flag = true;

   } else if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
       System.out.println("Hiiii");
   } else if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_GATEWAY) {
       System.out.println("Hi 1");
   } else if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_INTERNAL_ERROR) {
       System.out.println("Hi 2");
   }
//        System.out.println("");
   return flag;
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
   new SMSGenerator().sendSMS("xxxxxxxxxx", "ManojYest1");
}
}
```

The problem with this code is that if I check the `if` condition as: `connection != null` then it establishes the connection and calls the method properly.  However, if I check the condition with `responseCode` as `connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK` then the following error is occurs:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected
   at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty(HttpURLConnection.java:3013)
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Just catch the exception.

Comment: have already catched the exception after closing input stream. Please check

Comment: try calling connect() before getting response codes.

Comment: called `connection.connect()` before getting `responseCode` but still same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Because a connection shouldn't be used like that. What you're attempting to do is along the following lines:

```
"Open" Connection
Get Response
|-> Connect (if not already connected)
|-> Read response data
setRequestProperty
|-> Check connected state - Oops! Already connected!
```

Which is not how you're supposed to use a UrlConnection. Rather, it expects you to do the following:

```
"Open" Connection
setRequestProperty
|-> Check connected state - Not Connected
getOutputStream
|-> Connect
|-> Create and return output stream
Write request to output stream
Get Response
|-> Connect (if not already connected)
|-> Send (empty) request
|-> Read response data
```

Is there a reason that you need to know that you'll get back an `OK` response *before* you send the data? Or you simply trying to verify that you have successfully connected to the endpoint?

It does not help that `openConnection` does not result in the connection object *actually connecting* to the target URL...

Comment: Actually here I am sending message based on the returned `HttpResponseCode`. So I will have to set request property only after checking the response code. Or is there any other way around it?

Comment: The point is that that doesn't make sense - the server is sending the response code to you based on what you sent to it. If you didn't send anything to the server, why are you checking the response code?

Comment: How can you get ETag header following this approach?

Answer (score -1):

While coding get the response code after you post the data it will work:

E.g.

```
responsecode  = con.getResponsecode();
```